# Creating table with T-SQL - can't see created tables in Object explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

use Microsoft SQL

Try to create table using T-SQL language. Code is very simple, executed succesfull, but i don't see created table in Object Explorer. Try restart/reconnect/refresh/reexecuting - result the same - cant see this table. 
Also try to do it manually (by right click mouse in tree in the Object explorer - all ok - can see just created table).

Code:

```
USE tempdb 
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Employees','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Employees;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees
(
    empid INT NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    hiredate DATE NOT NULL,
    mgrid INT NULL,
    ssn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    salary MONEY NOT NULL
);
```

Screen shot

[image]

Think that the problem is very simple, but try to find answer and stack a little bit. Why i don't see just created table? Is this code is correct for creating table?

Comment: Do you intend the new table to appear in the `tempdb` database or `testdb` database? The SQL you provided creates the table in `tempdb` but the screenshot of the Object Explorer shows that you're looking for the new table in `testdb`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are creating that table in TempDB.

[image]

From this drop down select the right DataBase.

OR

execute the following statement before you execute the Create Table Statement. Something like

```
USE TestDB
GO

Create Table ....
```

Comment: oh, yep, now it's ok, stupid mistake, thanks, accept answer in 5 min

Comment: Not a problem we all make this mistake every now and then :)